# Outlook displays "This is an HTML email."

Tags: python, email, html-email

When i send my email via python. Outlook displays "This is an HTML email.". Gmail works fine.

This is the body:

## Create the email body with the sorted URLs

```
 body = "<html><body><div style='background-color: #0072c6; padding: 10px;'>"
 body += "<h2 style='color: #fff; margin: 0;'>Latest News:</h2>"
 body += "</div><ul style='list-style-type: none; padding: 0;'>"
 for url_info in matching_urls:
     summary, title, date, name, keywords, url = url_info
     body += f"<li style='margin-bottom: 10px;'><strong><a href=\"{url}\" style='color: 
     body += f"<span style='font-size: 14px;'><strong>Date:</strong> {date}</span><br>"
     body += f"<span style='font-size: 14px;'><strong>Summary:</strong> {summary}</span><br>"
     body += f"<span style='font-size: 14px;'><strong>Keywords:</strong> 

 body += "</ul></body></html>"

 em = EmailMessage()
 em["From"] = sender_email
 em["To"] = ", ".join(reciever_emails)  # Combine recipient emails with commas

 em["Subject"] = subject
 em.set_content("This is an HTML email.", subtype="html")
 em.add_alternative(body, subtype="html")
 file_path = "/tmp/News.xlsx"
 # Attach the Excel file to the email
 with open(file_path, "rb") as excel_file:
     em.add_attachment(
         excel_file.read(),
         maintype="application",
         subtype="vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
         filename="News.xlsx"
    )

 context = ssl.create_default_context()

 with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as smtp:
     smtp.login(sender_email, password)
     smtp.sendmail(sender_email, reciever_emails, em.as_string())`
```

Comment: Because you explicitly `set_content` to that. It's doing exactly what you asked it to.

Comment: (As an aside, I don't think you need to create and pass in a context any longer; this clumsy hack was necessary many years ago, but the API should be sane now.)

Comment: Many marketers have the distasteful habit to put a useless `text/plain` part which basically says, "If you prefer plain text over HTML because you have a physical disability, we hate you for being disabled. If you just happen to prefer plain text, we just hate you." Put a useful plaintext part, or don't supply one at all. In the latter case, if a spam filter hates you back, it's tempting to say you deserve it.